# guardar registro de tabla mysqli php

Tags: php, mysqli

hola amigos necesito de su ayuda pronta y urgente.
tengo una tabla donde muestro informacion de clientes que coinsiden y no coinsidencia con una comparacion de dos tablas. 
quiero es guardar esa informacion en tablas diferentes . 
los que son validos quiero guardarlos en validos y los invalidos quiero guardarlos en una taba invalidos. 
este es mi codigo
index.php

```html
<?php
    require_once ("./app/conexion.php");
    session_start();
    // Establece los mensajes de sesion
    $_SESSION['message'] = "";
    //Valida si es enviado por post
    //Valida si es enviado por post
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['deuda'])) { // aqui me introduce los datos en registro empleados
            require_once './app/deuda.php'; //requiere de registro empleados
        } 
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pagos Listos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Administradores Registrados</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="continer-alerta"> 
            <div style="color:#fff;"class="mensaje-alerta">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['message'] ?> 
            </div>
                </br></br>
        </div>    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Aqui se visualizara los pagos validos y los no validos
                    </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form>
                                <table method="post" action="#" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example" >
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Ticket</th>
                                            <th>Usuario</th>
                                            <th>Cedula</th>
                                            <th>Referencia</th>
                                            <th>Monto</th>
                                            <th>Estatus</th>
                                            <th>Reportado</th>
                                            <th>Comentario</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <?php
                                    //Clase para manejar la conexion a la base de datos
                                    class Connect
                                    {
                                        private $user = "root";//usuario de mysqlk
                                        private $pass = "";//clave de mysql
                                        private $base = "radius";//base de datos en mysql
                                        private $server = "localhost";//servidor de alojamiento
                                        public  $error;//en caso de error se almacena aqui
                                        public  $db;
                                        public  function __construct(){
                                            $mysqli = new mysqli($this->server, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->base);
                                            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                                                $this->error = "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
                                            }
                                            $this->db = $mysqli;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //Clase trabajo que se extiende de Connect
                                    class Trabajo extends Connect
                                    {
                                        public function __construct(){
                                            parent::__construct();
                                        }
                                        public function valida($x){
                                                $a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM archivos_pagos WHERE referencia = '$x' ");
                                                
                                                
                                        $t = $a->num_rows;

                                                if($t>=1){
                                                    //Si el cliente realizó el pago retorno la información
                                                    $row = $a->fetch_object();
                                                    return $row;
                                                }else{
                                                    //si no retorno falso
                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                        }
                                        public function data(){
                                            $a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM pagos_pagina");
                                            $con=1;
                                            while($row = $a->fetch_object()){
                                                //Envío a validar la referencia del cliente
                                                $valida = $this->valida($row->referencia);
                                              

                                                if($valida){                           
                                        echo "<tr> 
                                            <td>".$con."</td>
                                            <td>".$row->nombre." ".$row->apellido."</td>
                                            <td>".$row->cedula."</td>
                                            <td>".$valida->referencia."</td>
                                            <td>".$row->monto."</td>
                                            <td>Valido</td>
                                            <td><a href='#'> <butoon type='button' class='btn btn-success'>Valido</button></a></td>
                                            <td><div class='panel-footer'>
                                            <div class='input-group'>
                                                <input id='btn-input 'type='text' class='form-control input-sm' placeholder='Escribe un Comentario' />
                                                <span class='input-group-btn'>
                                                    <button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' id='btn-chat'> Enviar </button>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div></td>

                                        </tr>";
                                    }else{
                                        echo "<tr>
                                                <td>".$con."</td>
                                                <td>".$row->nombre." ".$row->apellido."</td>
                                                <td>".$row->cedula."</td>
                                                <td>".$row->referencia."</t>
                                                <td>".$row->monto."</t>
                                                <td>Invalido</td>
                                                <td><a href='#'> <butoon type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Invalido</button></a></td>
                                                <td><div class='panel-footer'>
                                                    <div class='input-group'>
                                                        <input id='btn-input 'type='text' class='form-control input-sm' placeholder='Escribe un Comentario' />
                                                        <span class='input-group-btn'>
                                                            <button class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' id='btn-chat'> Enviar </button>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div></td>
                                            </tr>";
                                            } 
                                            $con++;
                                            }
                                            echo "</table>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    $p = new trabajo();
                                    $p->data();
                                    ?>
                                    
                                </table>
                            </form>    
                        </div>    
                    </div>    
                </div>               
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

security/config.ini

[database]
username = root
password = 
dbname = radius

app/deuda.php

```html
<?php
    $ticket = $conn->escape_string($_POST['ticket']);
    $usuario = $conn->escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
    $cedula = $conn->escape_string($_POST['cedula']);
    $referencia = $conn->escape_string($_POST['referencia']);
    $monto = $conn->escape_string($_POST['monto']);
    $estatus = $conn->escape_string($_POST['estatus']);
    $telefono = $conn->escape_string($_POST['telefono']);
    $comentario = $conn->escape_string($_POST['comentario']);

            $sql = 
                "INSERT INTO deuda (
                    ticket, 
                    usuario, 
                    cedula, 
                    referencia, 
                    monto,
                    estatus,
                    telefono,
                    comentario
                    ) 
                    "."
                    VALUES (
                        '$ticket',
                        '$usuario',
                        '$cedula',
                        '$referencia',
                        '$monto',
                        '$estatus',
                        '$telefono',
                        '$comentario'
                )";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Su informacion a sigo guardado correctamente ';
                } else {
                    // Devuelve un mensaje de error
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Ocurrio un error al guardar la informacion';
                 }
```

app/validos.php

```html
<?php
    $ticket = $conn->escape_string($_POST['ticket']);
    $usuario = $conn->escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
    $cedula = $conn->escape_string($_POST['cedula']);
    $referencia = $conn->escape_string($_POST['referencia']);
    $monto = $conn->escape_string($_POST['monto']);
    $estatus = $conn->escape_string($_POST['estatus']);
    $telefono = $conn->escape_string($_POST['telefono']);
    $comentario = $conn->escape_string($_POST['comentario']);

            $sql = 
                "INSERT INTO validos(
                    ticket, 
                    usuario, 
                    cedula, 
                    referencia, 
                    monto,
                    estatus,
                    telefono,
                    comentario
                    ) 
                    "."
                    VALUES (
                        '$ticket',
                        '$usuario',
                        '$cedula',
                        '$referencia',
                        '$monto',
                        '$estatus',
                        '$telefono',
                        '$comentario'
                )";
                if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Su informacion a sigo guardado correctamente ';
                } else {
                    // Devuelve un mensaje de error
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Ocurrio un error al guardar la informacion';
                 }
```

app/conexion.php

```html
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $config = parse_ini_file('./security/config.ini');

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
?>
```

Comment: ¿Ya existen esas tablas de las que hablas (válidos, inválidos)? ¿Cuándo quieres guardar los datos en ellas? ¿Al presionar el botón Enviar `id="btn-chat"` de cada fila?

Comment: asi es ya existen tienen los mismos campos . los invalidos son invalidos y los validos son deudores .

Comment: Entonces, ¿cuál es tu duda? Pareciera que lo tienes todo hecho ya. ¿Te arroja algún error?

Comment: exelente no me registra nada no me da error no me dice nada simplemente se que algo esta bien pero no logro que funcione

Comment: Si no te está arrojando error (supongo que tampoco te muestra los mensajes que tú definiste para cuando ejecuta la query, ni éxito ni error, ¿cierto?), entonces te sugiero que actives los mensajes de error de PHP: agrega `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al inicio de todos los scripts que estás usando ahora, y a ver si se te informa de algo ([PHP: error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php)).

Comment: no pasa nada . mi url cambia de localhot a (http://localhost/?comentario=josias&validos=validos&comentario=&comentario=&comentario=&comentario=)

Comment: buenas prove con eso y nada solo quisiera guardr mi comentario si esta valido o no

Comment: no me da errores de nada

Comment: amigos estoy aqui no me olviden porfavor